# React Slick problem with video playing on center mode because multiple video on top on original

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

Here, @drorsun has explained the issue:
https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/issues/300

and here is the sandbox to play with:
https://codesandbox.io/s/slick-slider-react-slick-bug-with-video-forked-967b5?file=/src/index.js

So what's happening here is, we are trying to implement autoplay video on center mode, and since the react slick has cloned the divs multiple videos are playing so only the video on top can be played or paused with controls but there is a video still playing the background.

Comment: I'm also having same issue.